# Database connection error while using .net core and mysql in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have a simple web API application in .net core with MySQL database and It works locally as well without docker. I have windows 10 Home edition and can't use docker directly and I have to use VirtualBox to using docker.

**Appsettings**

```
"DatabaseConfig": {
    "Server": "db",
    "Port": "3306",
    "Database": "CoreApiDatabase",
    "User": "root",
    "Password": "27101376"
  }
```

**ConfigureServices**

```
var server = Configuration["DatabaseConfig:Server"];
var port = Configuration["DatabaseConfig:Port"];
var database = Configuration["DatabaseConfig:Database"];
var user = Configuration["DatabaseConfig:User"];
var password = Configuration["DatabaseConfig:Password"];

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseMySql($"server={server}; userid={user}; pwd={password}; port={port}; database={database}"));
```

migration and seed the database in Configure method in startup.cs

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env app/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","CoreApiDatabase.dll" ]
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
        ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 27101376
    networks:
      - default

  coreapidatabase:
    image: saeedgz98/coreapidatabase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    restart: always
```

and finally, when running command *docker-compose up* I get this error while executing and doing migrations.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing`database=` with `schema=` in the connection string?

Comment: I'd also try replacing `"Server": "db"` line in .json to `"Server": "localhost"` as I couldn't find a clue that suggests `db` refers to the correct server.

Comment: yes and get "System.ArgumentException: Option 'schema' not supported" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a terrible luck running setting up mysql with root user and running it on some remote machine. MySQL has some strict permission requirements root@localhost is different that root@127.0.0.1 for example. Or that's what I have undrestood. If you find out otherwise please share.

Just trying to help here. Switch to another connection string form

#### appsettings.json

```
"server=<database name from docker-compose >;port=3306;userid=<database owner>;password=<owner password>;database=<database name>;"
```

The docker-compose might look like the below:

#### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  moviedb:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <database name>
      MYSQL_USER: <database owner>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <owner password>
```

#### dockerfile

Avoid writing custom dockerfile. use the one that visual studio creates and make amends to that file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["<project relative path>", "<project name>/"]
RUN dotnet restore "<project relative path>"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/<project name>"
RUN dotnet build "<csproj name>" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "<csproj name>" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<project dll name>"]
```

You can also run below docker commands and try to log in to the database server

#### Debugging tips:

```
docker-compose up
docker ps
docker exec -it <sql container id> bash
```

Once inside the container. Run below mysql commands:

```
mysql -u <owner name> -p 
<owner password>
SHOW DATABASES; 
USE <database name>; 
SHOW TABLES;
```